# Meteor JS template subscription: cannot query data with find() even after Template.instance().subscriptionReady()

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm a newbie with Meteor, and I'm going crazy trying to make template subscriptions to work.

Even though Template.subscriptionsReady() returns true, I'm still getting "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined" when trying to find().fetch the collection. Follow the relevant snippets (and please let me now if I can include any more info):

Creating the collection (lib/collections/jobs.js):

```
Jobs = new Mongo.Collection('jobs');
```

My publication (server) (server/publish.js):

```
Meteor.publish('jobs', function (userId) {
  return Jobs.find({
    $or: [
      {
        uIDHirer: this.userId
          },
      {
        uIDProvider: this.userId
          }
        ]
  });
});
```

My subscription (client) (client/templates/calendar/calendar.js):

```
Template.Calendar.onCreated(function () {
  this.subscribe('jobs');
});
```

Then when I try to search the collection (client) (client/templates/calendar/calendar.js):

```
Template.Calendar.onRendered(function () {

  this.autorun(() => {

    if (Template.instance().subscriptionsReady()) {

          let data = Jobs.find({}).fetch();
    }

  });
});
```

Template.subscriptionsReady is correctly returning 1 when ready, but still can't search the collection. What am I missing? I assumed that when subscriptionReady I'd be able to find().fetch() the collection.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The error points to the "let data = Jobs.find({}).fetch();" line.

Comment: please update the question to show the paths of all the files. anything inside /imports is not automatically imported. so e.g if you define the collection somewhere in /imports, but don't use the JS import/export module features, then "Jobs" won't be known and you'll see the error you're seeing.

Comment: Hi @zim, I included all the patches from the app root. I'm using iron the iron scaffolding structure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I also have "import { Jobs } from '../../../lib/collections/jobs.js';" in the calendar.js file.

Comment: Another input, the publishing and subscription appear to be working, I can see the subscribed collection using Mongol.

Comment: just as a question - why do you autorun in onRendered and not in onCreated?

Comment: Hello @Jankapunkt, I did this because I want the data to be subscribed once when the template is created and the routine in the onRendered has to be run several times until the data is subscribed.

Comment: You can achieve that in the onCreated, too by subscribing before instance.autorun and wait for subscription.ready within outrun, plus you do not have to struggle with different template phases. Maybe your problem is, literally caused by that. You can give it a try.

Comment: Not sure it's the right way though. If I include a console.log inside the onRendered function I can see that it runs once when the subscriptions are not ready and on the second time, when subscriptionsReady==true it crashes because "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined", meaning Jobs is returning undefined. 
I tried including an autorun in the onCreated (subscription) with no effect and when I remove the autorun from onRendered the routine only runs once and do not do anything since subscriptionsReady is false. Thank you!

Comment: @Jankapunkt will try it right now, and will let you know how it goes, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Jankapunkt I tryed it and got the same results. The autorun function is working, as is the subscriptionsReady. I can see it runs once when subscriptions are not yet ready and then once again when ready, and this is when it crashes, even with the subscriptionsReady Jobs is not found (there is one record in the collection, and the collection is published to the client, since I can inspect it in Mongol). I've tried just about anything, no luck yet

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by removing

```
import {
  Jobs
} from '../../../lib/collections/jobs.js';
```

from the calendar.js file. Not sure why though, I'd be thankful if someone could help me understand.

Thanks @zim and @Jankapunkt for the assistance!

Comment: seems that you did not export Jobs but put it in global namespace?

Comment: @Jankapunkt, that sounds right. and then the import failed because jobs.js didn't export Jobs, thus Jobs was undefined. by deleting the import, you are now getting Jobs from the global namespace. if you "export {Jobs}" in jobs.js, then you should be able to restore your import.

Comment: sorry, where "you" is Fabio.

Comment: Got it :)    Thanks @Jankapunkt!